# Activity lifecycle confusion

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I'm new to Android development so please excuse my ignorance.

I have two activties, A + B.  If go from A->B, A keeps retained and it does not get destroyed. When I go back from B->A (using the back button), activity A gets destroyed and created again then activity B gets destroyed.

I was looking for a way to retain activity A, so when I go back B->A, A is retained like it was. I was able to achieve this via setting activity A launchMode like so `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

Can anybody explain the initial behavior? or at least direct me to some material to read? Why is A destroyed when I press back in B?

What if I want to achieve the effect of `android:launchMode="singleTop"` programmatically, should I catch the "Back" call in B and create my own `Intent` with my own flags?

Is setting the launchMode to singleTop the correct way to achieve what I wanted?

Comment: Please post your manifest. The behaviour you are seeing is not normal, nor standard. There is something weird going on. Normal behaviour is: pressing BACK in ActivityB will destroy activity B and resume existing instance of ActivityA.

Comment: @DavidWasser Manifest: http://pastebin.com/Rx74rZ28, The behavior with this manifest, clicking back in ActivityB = ActivityA Destroyed -> ActivityA Created -> ActivityB Destroyed. If I add android:launchMode="singleTop" to ActivityA ('Main' in manifest), the behavior = ActivityA is resumed and ActivityB is destroyed.

Comment: Manifest looks OK. Are your activity classes derived from Android `Activity` or are you using some framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a bit confused. The situation you've described matches the behaviour of "UP" navigation. In your post you described going from B->A using the "BACK" button (hardware button on the device). But based on your description, you must be talking about the "UP" button (soft ">" icon in the action bar at the top of the screen). If you want to have the UP navigation use the existing instance of activity A (instead of creating a new one), then you need to set  `launchMode="singleTop"` in the `<activity>` definition for activity A in the manifest.

See [documentation for UP navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) for details about this. Here's a quote of the relevant bit:

> To navigate up when the user presses the app icon, you can use the
>   NavUtils class's static method, `navigateUpFromSameTask()`. When you
>   call this method, it finishes the current activity and starts (or
>   resumes) the appropriate parent activity. If the target parent
>   activity is in the task's back stack, it is brought forward. The way
>   it is brought forward depends on whether the parent activity is able
>   to handle an `onNewIntent()` call:
>
> - If the parent activity has launch mode `<singleTop>`, or the up intent contains `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, the parent activity is
>     brought to the top of the stack, and receives the intent through its
>     `onNewIntent()` method.
> - If the parent activity has launch mode `<standard>`, and the up intent does not contain `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, the parent activity
>     is popped off the stack, and a new instance of that activity is
>     created on top of the stack to receive the intent.

Comment: Thanks for this, finally everything makes sense. I'm new to Android development and I thought that 'UP' from action bar is just an alternative to the physical back button, guess not. By the way, is it OK if I override the behavior of 'UP' at some points in my application? I have some kind of a wizard (1 activity, many fragments) and I made the 'UP' navigate through fragments instead of activities (until it reaches the first fragment, then it navigates through activities), just wondering if that design is OK.

Comment: In general, the BACK button should go back to the previous step. the UP navigation should go back to the previous level or just back to the starting screen. This is just a general rule. All applications have somewhat different requirements. IMHO most users will use the BACK button and not (as on an iPhone) use the UP navigation. Your mileage may vary ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
When I go back from B->A (using the back button), activity A gets destroyed and created again.
```

I think the way you are looking at concepts your above statement is wrong.

Activity A never get destroyed rather it goes into `onStop()` state of Activity lifecycle and when user press back button it resumes if you know the Activity Lifecycle

[image]

When the current activity starts another, the new activity is pushed on the top of the stack and takes focus. **The previous activity remains in the stack, but is stopped**. When an activity stops, the system retains the current state of its user interface. When the user presses the Back button, the current activity is popped from the top of the stack (the activity is destroyed) and **the previous activity resumes** (the previous state of its UI is restored).

**EDITS :**

```
activity A gets destroyed and created again
```

This is possible in following cases:

- If you don't explicitly shut down your first activity when starting the new one.
- If you override the `onBackPressed` in your second activity to start the first one.
  Example:

  `@Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
      startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class));
  }`

Comment: By default, this is not what's happening. I was talking based on observations. Here is the log (without using singleTop, everything's at default).
`09-20 09:23/com.x.x V/﹕ Activity A is created.
Launched new activtiy:
09-20 09:23/com.x.x V/﹕ Activity B is created.

Pressed Back:
09-20 09:23/com.x.x V/﹕ Activity A is Destroyed
09-20 09:23/com.x.x V/﹕ Activity A is created.
09-20 09:23/com.x.x V/﹕ Activity B is Destroyed`

Comment: @lenix looking at your logcat it is possible but it depends on code you write.I can explain it if you post your code of `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`

Comment: I'm not explicitly shutting down A after launching B (not calling finish()), so I guess that explains a bit. The question now, how can I retain A? is the solution mentioned in OP correct?